# Logstash JSON Parse - Ignore or Remove Sub-Tree

Tags: json, filter, logstash, kibana

I'm sending JSON to logstash with a config like so:

```
filter {
    json {
      source => "event"
      remove_field => [ "event" ]
    }
  }
```

Here is an example JSON object I'm sending:

```
   {
      "@timestamp": "2015-04-07T22:26:37.786Z",
      "type": "event",
      "event": {
        "activityRecord": {
          "id": 68479,
          "completeTime": 1428445597542,
          "data": {
            "2015-03-16": true,
            "2015-03-17": true,
            "2015-03-18": true,
            "2015-03-19": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Because of the arbitrary nature of the `activityRecord.data` object, I don't want logstash and elasticsearch to index all these date fields.  As is, I see `activityRecord.data.2015-03-16` as a field to filter on in Kibana.

Is there a way to ignore this sub-tree of data?  Or at least delete it after it has already been parsed?  I tried `remove_field` with wildcards and whatnot, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not entirely intuitive it is [documented](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/configuration#fieldreferences) that subfield references are made with square brackets, e.g. [field][subfield], so that's what you'll have to use with remove_field:

```
mutate {
  remove_field => "[event][activityRecord][data]"
}
```

To delete fields using wildcard matching you'd have to use a [ruby filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/ruby).

Comment: Thanks, ruby block works with: 
`if [event] and [event][activityRecord] {
      ruby {
          code => "event['event']['activityRecord']['data'] = {}"
      }
    }`